# Use multiple citation styles in a single document?

Tags: bibtex, multibib

I need to have citations from one bibliography file show as author, year and those from another bibliography show up as a number style in the same document.

I have used multibib to work with both bibliographies, but I have not been able to figure out how to provide multiple citation styles.

Comment: This would be relatively easy to do with `biblatex`. Is that an option for you to use?

Comment: I'm not really sure what would prevent compatibility (I'm not familiar with biblatex, beyond that it exists). I have provided .cls and .bst files from the journal, though I can probably hack them without ill effect.